# Painting a dog with texture paint, TOTAL NOOB

Tags: texture-painting

I started blender and made a model of a dog. I tried painting the dog but it would not paint in the areas I wanted it to. It paints in random spots all around. I'm stuck. Here is the picture.

As you can see, I only put the brush on the eyes, but it painted the legs and nose too. The brush did not touch any other area but the eyes[image: PaintingTheDog]

Comment: on the left, on the UV map part, you can see that the eyes of the boar are overlapping the other parts of the UV map. So that's like eyes and these other parts share the same texture part.

Comment: How do i fix it

Comment: enter edit mode (tab), you'll see UV map on left view. Here you can select and move the UV map parts (same way as you can select, move, scale, etc in the 3D view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to unwrap mesh into UV editor in Edit mode.

STEP 1: Goto "Edit mode" in 3D viewport by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> key or using the menu below
[image]

Once you are in Edit mode like this

Drag the window below just like this
[image]

Now, follow the image below to go into UV Editor.

[image]

Then hit <kbd>U</kbd> in 3D viewport and press "Unwrap" in the menu from the image below

[image]

After the unwrap you'll get unwrapped mesh in UV Editor something like the below image.

[image]

But you can see that all the unwrapped mesh is overlapped in UV Editor in image no.5.
You have the same problem with the mesh.

Now the solution starts.

You need to select the vertices of the mesh so that when unwrapped it needs to be unwrapped good. Check out the reference cube image that has its vertices selected.

[image][image]

After the selection of vertices in the mesh hit <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> in 3D Viewport and select "Mark Seam".
[image]

Then hit select all the vertices <kbd>A+8</kbd> x2times, after all the vertices are selected, Hit <kbd>U</kbd> and select "Unwrap".

[image]

Now, after the mesh is unwrapped correctly, create new texture

[image]

And continue your Texture Painting.

Comment: You're Welcome!