# Texture Painting not working on some parts

Tags: texturing

Sup. I made a Knife Model recently, and tried to texture paint on it. The Problem is, that there are Parts where it works and parts where it doesnt, and only changes the solid color if I paint somewhere. If I open it as OBJ there is a different part which is just black and cant change the color. Is there a way to "rasterize" the object as in Photoshop, so i can paint all over it? And yes, its a single mesh i guess...

Try Texturing all over it please: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AOTmQfrKYmQ0X-Pz1rQ9HU_E_SLflNA1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Its because your mesh is not unwrapped correctly. Check out this link to know how to unwrap a mesh -->  [Painting a dog with texture paint, TOTAL NOOB](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168793/painting-a-dog-with-texture-paint-total-noob/168798#168798)

[image]

I've tried unwrapping your mesh but the sword shell mesh was not good, its mesh was overlapping. So i've just unwrapped blade and handle.

[image]

1st mark the seam using <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> and then <kbd>U</kbd> and Select Unwrap.
[image]

This is how a mesh is unwrapped. It should not be overlapped, unless you want same texture on it.
[image]

I'm not a teacher but here are some Remarks after seeing the mesh :
Try making different objects in this case eg., sword,shell,handle etc.,then and after its texturing is done (or) applying the materials, join the objects into single object using <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>. Don't make everything in same object from the start.

Hope your problem is solved.

Comment: damn thats a great tutorial, would u be down to send me the file?

Comment: hope u saved it :O

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Q7X8XS5d/

Comment: but unwrapped only for blade and handle as shell was overlapping..